# How can implement Horizontal listview in listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a view like parent view is a listview, each row is a listview too. because i will call some method when list be scroll to bottom (both view parent listview and row listview).

How can i implement, is it impossible ?
Thank alot!

Comment: each row is a horizontal listivew

Answer (score 0):

You can use Devsmart library for Horizontal ListView , I have used it before and seems pretty good to me.

http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

But I am not sure why you need a horizontal listview in each row of a ListView. Because you can use GridView to do it more easily and efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, cuz each row i want is able to scroll and when scroll to bottom i will call my function... it is my task, i also no seen it before @@

Comment: Then you have to use the above library.

Comment: This library can't detect on scroll